# How to fit a Garch(1,1) Model with the package rugarch, with external regressors in the mean- and in the variance equation?

Tags: r, time-series, autoregressive-models

I want to estimate an Ar(1)-Garch(1,1) Model in R, using the package rugarch. I am running a test run right now and have a problem with including external regressors in my model. I can either include an external regressor in my mean equation or my variance equation, but not both(which is what I need). Ugarchspec doesn't give me an error message but when I want to fit the model, the following error message occurs:

Error in pars[idx["mxreg", 1]:idx["mxreg", 2], 1] <- fit.mean[i] : 
  replacement has length zero

What am I doing wrong? The data (Reg1) I am using is a time series.(Please ignore that it is just 40 observations, it is just a test run)

I tried it with my external regressor in just my mean equation and it worked perfectly fine, I also tried it with matrices instead of time series data.

```
Spec1<- ugarchspec(
  variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1), 
                        external.regressors =Reg1[1:40,1:2]), 
  mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,0), include.mean = F,
                        external.regressors =Reg1[1:40,2]), distribution.model = "std")

fit1 <-ugarchfit(spec=Spec1,data=Reg1[1:40,1])

Error in pars[idx["mxreg", 1]:idx["mxreg", 2], 1] <- fit.mean[i] : 
  replacement has length zero


> Reg1[1:40]
              weekreturn   weekreturn1
2010-11-03  0.0018533675  0.0066020518
2010-11-10  0.0054522440  0.0072355717
2010-11-17 -0.0080023499 -0.0175327649
2010-11-24 -0.0006116435  0.0083274354
2010-12-01  0.0045637580  0.0084704193
2010-12-08  0.0035956818  0.0034966325
2010-12-15 -0.0009122183  0.0007687969
2010-12-22  0.0022032432  0.0041542532
2010-12-29  0.0118825438  0.0017621218
2011-01-05 -0.0023936587 -0.0018079717
2011-01-12  0.0051343640  0.0034256437
2011-01-19  0.0091805311 -0.0027364546
2011-01-26  0.0013110765 -0.0079251628
2011-02-02  0.0004902113  0.0079251628
2011-02-09  0.0027050851 -0.0093501286
2011-02-16 -0.0080829036 -0.0040071230
2011-02-23 -0.0065242275  0.0358634410
2011-03-02  0.0093583210  0.0082475620
2011-03-09 -0.0056961698  0.0041625819
2011-03-16 -0.0193926662 -0.0126549420
2011-03-23  0.0158149375  0.0152628883
2011-03-30  0.0042398967 -0.0028188258
2011-04-06  0.0131899706  0.0085606686
2011-04-13  0.0050939083 -0.0031861376
2011-04-20  0.0031597325  0.0079439432
2011-04-27 -0.0032323717  0.0029214016
2011-05-04 -0.0028337146 -0.0063428739
2011-05-11 -0.0069015444 -0.0212878507
2011-05-18  0.0051629648  0.0038123286
2011-05-25 -0.0012130035  0.0024228278
2011-06-01  0.0083575515 -0.0025544590
2011-06-08  0.0042632089  0.0008953902
2011-06-15 -0.0104308821 -0.0121336103
2011-06-22 -0.0067400310  0.0012617012
2011-06-29  0.0092369278 -0.0013460983
2011-07-06 -0.0035327721  0.0049108255
2011-07-13  0.0006245218  0.0028762694
2011-07-20 -0.0001176851  0.0001834956
2011-07-27  0.0003880984 -0.0015137640
2011-08-03  0.0023767744 -0.0115597586
```

Help would be highly appreciated, since it is for my masters thesis. Thank you!

Comment: when I pass your variable as a matrix, I do not get an error in the specification.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: I did what you suggested, I passed the variable as a matrix. Thank you for your time and help.